# Ajax callback not executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form page that I intend submitting using Ajax. My plan is to
    1. Check if email already exists using Ajax
    2. Check if passwords match
    3. If it does, switch to another "screen" and
    4. Submit the form using Ajax

I'm confused because the validate function does not run. It neither switches screens not alerts when passwords do not match. As such, the form does not get submitted either. My code goes below

```
$('form input:last-child').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var allFields = e.target.parentNode;

    function validate () {
        if (allFields.elements[3].value !== allFields.elements[4].value) {
            return false; // If they don't match, return false
        } else {
            $('#form-div form').css('left', '-70%');
            $('#confirm p').css('margin-left', '-12%'); // else switch screens
        }
    }
    if (validate != false) {
        $('#hidden').load("server_script.php"); // `hidden` is a hidden div somewhere on the page
    } else 
        alert ("Passwords do not match");
});
```

I'm thinking, if they don't match, the rest of the event listener won't run since the false terminates the function from that point on. So I tried making an instance of the validate function outside the event listener and calling it inside the click function but it won't parse because of dependency variables so I'm not sure how to go about this.

**UPDATE**
Associated HTML attached. (Bonus: the regex pattern does not match 2 or more letters)

```
<div id=form-div>
<form method=POST action="" >
First Name: <br> <input type=text name=first_name pattern="[a-z]{2,}" required /> <br> <br>
Last Name: <br> <input type=text name=last_name pattern="[a-z]{2,}" required /> <br> <br>
Email: <span id=emailReport></span> <br> <input type=email name=email id=email required /> <br> <br>
Password: <br> <input type=password name=password required pattern=".{6,}" title="Password must be six or more characters" /> <br> <br>
Confirm password: <br> <input type=password name=password required /> <br> <br>
<input type=hidden name=sign_up_date />
<input type=submit value='sign up' />
</form>

<div id=confirm> <p>Some text</p> </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Without the associated HTML its difficult to be of any assistance

Comment: What is `validate != false`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly added the html

Comment: @u_mulder I'm trying to check if the output of the validate function did not return false. If that is the case, then run below code

Comment: Sensible code indentation makes code easier to read, but help a lot more in debuggeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the 'validate' function.
As it seems by your code you just declared the function without executing him.

Comment: Actually he thought he was calling it if you look a little closer

Answer (score 0):

The `validate` function is not being called.  Why not simply remove the function definition so the code is part of the `click` function?

Comment: If I unwrap it, how then do I test for non similar passwords?

Comment: You could move it outside of the `click` function as a standalone function and pass in the values to compare as parameters: `function validate(pass1, pass2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the validate function **properly**

Function calls must have the `()` i.e. `validate()` and not `validate`

```
$('form input:last-child').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var allFields = e.target.parentNode;

    function validate () {
        if (allFields.elements[3].value !== allFields.elements[4].value) {
            return false; // If they don't match, return false
        } else {
            $('#form-div form').css('left', '-70%');
            $('#confirm p').css('margin-left', '-12%'); // else switch screens
        }
    }

    //if (validate != false) {
    if (validate() != false) {  
        $('#hidden').load("server_script.php"); // `hidden` is a hidden div somewhere on the page
    } else 
        alert ("Passwords do not match");
});
```

Comment: I added the parenthesis but the script does not load any ways. The reason the original `validate` wasn't running was, I had not called it on a separate line. Please check accepted answer

Comment: This would call the `validate()` function assuming this whole section of js code was actually being called. Are you saying this whole section of code was not being called??